# Why does my printk messages are updated in the log file lately?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I have written a simple module as follows:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>


static int __init own_init(void)
{

    printk(KERN_INFO "Hi");

    return 0;
}

static int __exit own_exit(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "bye");

}

module_init(own_init);
module_exit(own_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

After installing this module, i am expecting **Hi**, but not displayed. 
But while am removing the module, **Hi** is displayed. 
When i am again inserting, **Bye** is displayed.

So there is a lag.

Why is that?

Comment: What happens if you add line termination, i.e. "\n", to your text?

Comment: Its working fine now. How dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you have forgot a newline at the end of your log message. When the kernel outputs a partial message (by passing a string to `printk()` that does not end with a newline), the logging system will buffer the text until the rest of the message arrives. See also — [`printk()` problems](http://lwn.net/Articles/503430/).